# cpr, getting html requests

Tags: c++, curl

So I am able to get the html request, I am using the library imgui for rendering and stuff, and I wanted to make something sort of a changelog, but when I go to print the text onto the gui it shows the whole code of the website like all the html stuff of it, I am using localhost rn to do it, is their something I can do to stop this?

Comment: I seriously doubt anyone can help given your current question.

Comment: show us the code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.